# C# change object's order and order of all siblings in same category

Tags: c#

I work on mini CMS with objects that have the parameter ORDER (int). Suppose I have 10 objects and each has its own ORDER from 1 to 10.

I want to move the 3rd element to the 8th position hence the 3 element should get the position (order) 8 and the 8 element is set to become 7 and 7-6 and 6-5 and so to 1 .....

And vice versa: if I move the 8 element to the 2 position, then the 8 element gets the order 2 2 gets 3, 3 gets 4 and so before the query.Coun

I wrote a crooked code which, when loaded, is buggy and produces a different result than I would like. Can anyone encountered such a problem educate ..

Sorry for my english here is my code:

```
 public static void UpdateJsTreeOrder(this IDocumentSession session, string pageId, string parent, string element)
    {

        var pages = session.Query<Page>().Where(x => x.ParentPageId == parent);
        var orderList = pages.Select(x => x.Order).Take(1024).ToList();
        var page = session.Load<Page>(pageId);

        if (element == null)
        {

            var subList = pages.Where(x => x.Order != page.Order).Take(1024).ToList();
            foreach (var item in subList)
            {
                item.Order++;
                session.Store(item);
            }
            page.Order = 1;
            session.Store(page);
            return;
        }


        var newOrder = session.Load<Page>(element).Order;


        if (!orderList.Any())
        {
            //its the first item
        }

        //last item 
        if (newOrder == orderList.Max())
        {
            var subList = pages.Where(x => x.Order <= newOrder && x.Order != page.Order).Take(1024).ToList();
            foreach (var item in subList)
            {
                item.Order--;
                session.Store(item);
            }
        }
        //first item
        else if (newOrder == orderList.Min())
        {
            var subList = pages;
            foreach (var item in subList)
            {
                item.Order--;
                session.Store(item);
            }
        }
        //int the middle
        else
        {
            var subList = pages.Where(x => x.Order >= newOrder || x.Order == newOrder).Take(1024).ToList();
            foreach (var item in subList)
            {
                item.Order--;
                session.Store(item);
            }
        }
        page.Order = newOrder;
        session.Store(page);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working LINQ (seems like you are) and have a collection you can manipulate, the following might work for you:

```
    int oldOrder = 8;
    int newOrder = 3;

    if (newOrder < oldOrder) {
        SmallBit moving = collection.Where(c => c.Order == oldOrder).First();
        collection.Where(c => c.Order >= newOrder && c.Order < oldOrder).ToList().ForEach(c => c.Order += 1);
        moving.Order = newOrder;

    } else {
        SmallBit moving = collection.Where(c => c.Order == oldOrder).First();
        collection.Where(c => c.Order > oldOrder && c.Order <= newOrder).ToList().ForEach(c => c.Order -= 1);
        moving.Order = newOrder;

    }
```

Edit: `SmallBit` in this case is simply the `page` object - I had renamed it in my fiddle.

Comment: thank you so much! It turned out with a small modification!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get desired result using Insert and RemoveAt Statement Like this

```
public static void UpdateJsTreeOrder(int from,int to)
        {
            var pages = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
            var item = pages.ElementAt(from);
            pages.RemoveAt(from);
            pages.Insert(to,item);
        }
```

This is just an example you can incorporate in your code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there's three (valid) cases...

- Item doesn't move
- Item moves to a larger Order, decrease the other items to make room.
- Item moves to a smaller Order, increase the other items to make room.

So, to address each case:

```
private void MoveItem(List<Page> source, int fromOrder, int toOrder)
{
  if (fromOrder == toOrder)
  { return; }

  if (fromOrder < toOrder)
  {
    foreach(Page page in source)
    {
      bool match = page.Order == fromOrder;
      bool between = fromOrder < page.Order && page.Order <= toOrder;
      page.Order = match ? toOrder :
         between ? page.Order - 1 :
         page.Order;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    foreach(Page page in source)
    {
      bool match = page.Order == fromOrder;
      bool between = toOrder <= page.Order && page.Order < fromOrder;
      page.Order = match ? toOrder :
         between ? page.Order + 1 :
         page.Order;
    }
  }
}
```